# MySQL - Index is not used on View

Tags: mysql, database, performance

**Mysql: 5.7**

I have two tables that is exactly same structure. Indexes are also same. Just different table name only. 
I created a View with these two tables like below.

```
CREATE ALGORITHM = MERGE VIEW TESTVW AS SELECT * FROM tableA UNION ALL SELECT * FROM tableB
```

**My problem**

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM TESTVW WHERE pk=3
```

[image]
There's no any used indexes in this result(even if other index columns are used in where clause). Can anyone help me what I'm wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `VIEW` processing is not smart enough to push the `WHERE` into the `SELECTs` of a `UNION`.  Run `EXPLAIN` to see that it does the `UNION` before applying the `WHERE`, and that there no `INDEX` available then.

VIEWs are syntactic sugar; they rarely help performance; sometimes they hurt.  In this case it does not hurt.  What hurts is that you can easily see how to improve the query; the optimizer fails.

To explain the explain:

- Run the two `SELECTs`
- `UNION ALL` them.  (This may have the recent optimization that avoids the need for a temp table.)
- But there still will be a temp table.
- Build an index (`<auto-key>`)
- Look up `pk=3` using that index.